# Get value as html in google spreadsheet script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is it possible to get value from sheet parsed as HTML? I'm getting single cell and sending it via email. I works great, but my email message is plain text. How to send parsed message in HTML (that will look like in spreadsheet) with bold, line breaks etc?

```
var message = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: 'demo@demo.com',
  htmlBody: message,
  subject: 'test'       
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
var html =  //YOUR HTML STRUCTURE
    '<body>' + 
      '<h2> Test </h2><br />' +
        '<p>'+ message +'</p>' +
    '</body>'   

MailApp.sendEmail(
    'your@emailaddress.com',         
    'Subject',                  
    'test', {                        // body
      htmlBody: html                 // advanced options
    }
  );
```

Just add your message to the structure.

Comment: This doesen't work. I can see in mail source that my message from cell is plain text, not formated. My question is how to get value from cell correctly formated with <b> for bold, <br /> for new line etc so it will look the same in cell and mail.

Comment: @norr i suposse that you must concat your cells content with your html tags. Something like '<b>' + cellContent + '</b>'. Notice that html tags are just stringified tags.

Comment: I know i can add HTML tags in cell field, but this not the point. I need to send cell formated by Spreadsheet normal options as mail, that will look like this cell so someone who do not know HTML can send formated email.

Comment: @norr Ohhhhh, ok. You want that your cells which you add to your message gets the same aspect that they have in your doc... I think that you can't do that. I mean, when you extract the content with a `getRange`, the text is saved, but the format not. In that case I suppose that you could send the full doc.